# Property 'view' does not exist on type 'HttpContextContract'.ts(2339) adonisjs

Tags: adonis.js

I am new in adonis jsand i am facing this error while creating controllers.

```
import { HttpContextContract } from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/HttpContext'

export default class LoginController{

    public async index({view}: HttpContextContract){
        return view.render('backend/login/login');

    }
}
```

this is main error in above code

> "Property 'view' does not exist on type 'HttpContextContract'.ts(2339)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you have the package `@adonisjs/view` installed and configured in your application.

Depending on the preset you choose when installing a new application, this module is not installed.

If you need to install it, follow the following steps:

1. Install the dependency `npm i @adonisjs/view`;
2. Configure it with `node ace configure @adonisjs/view`.

Documentation: https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/views/introduction#setup